# Qt: Add qml.qrc to git repository or to .gitignore?

Tags: git, qt, qml, qtquick2

I'm wondering weather the qml.qrc file gets completely generated by QMake through the other *.qml files? So can I safely add the qml.qrc to the .gitignore file? Or does it contain some other important information such as which files it contains?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is file which describes which files should be written into the exe with XML format. 
Take a look on the structure. For example:

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">//your prefix
        <file>description.txt</file>//txt file
        <file>SolarSystem.qml</file>//source
        <file>images/earth.png</file>//pictures
        <file>images/jupiter.png</file>
        <file>images/logo.png</file>
        <file>images/mars.png</file>
        <file>images/mercury.png</file>
        <file>images/neptun.png</file>
        <file>images/saturn.png</file>
        <file>images/sun.png</file>
        <file>images/uran.png</file>
        <file>images/venera.png</file>
        <file>images/icon.png</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

So it can be importamt.

Comment: Thanks, that answers my question. I always understood it that way, that the qrc-file is a binary already. So I never tried opening it with a text editor. I did not know that it only specifies which files will be compiled into the binary _later_. Slowly I'm getting better with Qt, also thanks to your help :)